# Have a webpage load up already scrolled so far down

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

I'm currently trying to figure a way to make a website load up and already be scrolled so far down.

For example...

**CSS**

```
body {
height:2000px;  
}

#red-box {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:150px;
background-color:red;
}

#blue-box {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:500px;
margin-top:150px;
background-color:blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="red-box"></div>
<div id="blue-box"></div>
```

Is there anyway I can make the webpage already be scrolled down far enough to make the red-box div already be off the top of the page. In other words, the page has already scrolled down 150px (the height of the red-box) when it loads up and in order to see the red-box, the user would have to manually scroll back up.

I've tried several JavaScripts but the only one that came remotely close to sort of working was...

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
   window.scrollTo(0,150);
});
```

But that does not do what I need and, in fact, makes the whole page unscrollable- It does scroll down to 150px, but only when the user manually scrolls the page by any ammount, and then it gets stuck there and won't scroll at all.

I'm not the greatest at JavaScript... I think my problem might have something to do with the

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
});
```

section. As I think

```
   window.scrollTo(0,150);
```

is what I actually want it to do. But I'm just guessing here and I can't seem to get it to work at all.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvHja/) to try and demonstrate a bit clearer.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting scroll position to 0(,150) on every scroll event which you don't want. You should do it only on page load. Change it to this code.

```
$(function() {
   window.scrollTo(0,150);
});
```

To make it perfectly scroll to the red box use this code. `offset()` method gives the top/left position of the element relative to the document.

```
$(function(){
   window.scrollTo(0, $('#red-box').offset().top));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `scrollTo()` method in a self-invoked anonymous function so that it auto executes without the need for instanciating a jQuery object.

`(function() { window.scrollTo(0,150); })();`

Or simpler yet, put it in your `<body`> tag.

`<body onload="window.scrollTo(0,150);">`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is right. The suggestions already posted should work fine, except Shankar's would require you include whatever library first.

Are you using a library? Such as jQuery, prototype, etc. The special characters in your first code snippet denote a library - if you haven't included it before that script in the document, that script won't work.

Also, in case you were curious:

`$(window)` brings the window object into the scope of the library. `.scroll` denotes the method and `(function(event) { });` is a callback.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm having a pretty hard time getting to grips with it all. I have a JQuery library included so it's all working now!